# Cocos2dv3: Renaming project causes Objective Chipmunk to not be found

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I clicked on the blue xcode project name in the TopLeft of the Project Navigator, and changed the name from "A" to "B", and now I'm getting an e-rror called :

```
ObjectiveChipmunk - 1 issue
cpSpaceQuery.c
! Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'chipmunk/chipmunk_private.h' file not found
```

Please give some help and I will love you for this.

Comment: Drag Chipmunk folder's parent folder to header search path window in Xcode target.

Answer (score 2):

Add the:
 "[ProjectPath]/Libraries/Chipmunk/chipmunk/include"
 or the path to chipmunk header fils.
to:
 Target -> Building Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths

If it's not work, you should check the project folder in Finder make sure the folder of chipmunk in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the right path on Header Search Paths. Check the Header Search Paths on Targets -> ObjectiveChipmunk as well. On my project, I set to:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/Chipmunk/objectivec/include"
"$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/Chipmunk/chipmunk/include"
```